# Find sobjects for which you can not give object permissions

Tags: permissions, profile, permission-sets

Does anyone know how to find objects in Salesforce for which you can not set object permission at all ?

if you look in the profile / permission set object permission list there are objects with "No access" and those for which you can no not give access at all (there is a - for these). I would like to find with API or SOQL the latter ones.

For example one object like this is `OpportunityLineItem`

In `EntityDefinition` object `IsFlsEnabled` is `true` for this object which sounds like it would be wrong

The object is listed on the UI because you can give field permission to the object but not object permissions

Comment: I quickly tried that out and it seems exactly what I was looking for, thanks!
The picklist value does not include OpportuntyLineItem which is correct